# Google Chart : Remove repetitive y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I am using google chart which is working absolutely fine except one thing the issue is when I select custom date filter and choose only single date from it then it will show only 1 record with little dot which is also fine no issue with that but its y axis shows repetitive values in it.

Please check example : 
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f757w8k3a

it shows 0, 1, 1, 2, 2
it should show 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or just 0, 1, 2

```
var options = {
                vAxis: {
                    format: '#',
                    minValue: 0,
                    gridlines: {
                        color: 'transparent'
                    },
                    viewWindowMode: "explicit",
                    viewWindow:{ min: 0 }
                },
                hAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
                legend: { position: 'none' },
                colors:[{color:'#A8D1FF', darker:'#97B9D8'}]
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('PostChart'));
            chart.draw(PostChartData, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

That may be cause of small range of values for Y axis. Try using Ticks for vAxis commonly referred as **vAxis.ticks**

```
vAxis: { ticks: [5,10,15,20] } //array
vAxis: { ticks: [{v:32, f:'thirty two'}, {v:64, f:'sixty four'}] } // A valid value as V
vAxis: { ticks: [new Date(2014,3,15), new Date(2013,5,15)] } // Dates
```

[Click Here for Ref.](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart?hl=en)

Edit1: In case your record values belongs to smaller range and and you have set the Max Value of vAxis to a higher value, It can also result in Repeated values in vAxis.

Comment: What if I've more than 20 records in some filter ?

Comment: Can you describe more a bit? Raw data to describe problem will help more.

Comment: At the same time if Records are more than 20 then i believe it will not give repeated numbers.

Comment: I use no of posts in between particular dates, sometimes it shows 1000's of records and sometimes 0, when it returns more records google automatically manage ticks correctly but with less records it show repetitive values and I can't even fix ticks because sometimes its 1000's and sometimes 0

Comment: Ticks values is an array, you get value for each date, get the maximum of them set as max. other thing you can try is divide the max by number of step size you want, you will get grid count . set grid count value with this. These are the things you can try, not tested though. Hope it Helps!